# Lookback:Meteor-seo broken?

Tags: javascript, meteor, lookback

Using meteor 1.5.2
I installed the latest lookback:meteor-seo plugin and im getting this error

```js
lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:245 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meta is not defined
    at Function.Iron.Router.plugins.seo (lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:245)
    at Function.Router.plugin (iron_router.js?hash=f36af52c3c2c3d66f1e99d1562e7d6bf92b00c1c:1326)
    at lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:310
    at lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:471
    at lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:478
Iron.Router.plugins.seo @ lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:245
Router.plugin @ iron_router.js?hash=f36af52c3c2c3d66f1e99d1562e7d6bf92b00c1c:1326
(anonymous) @ lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:310
(anonymous) @ lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:471
(anonymous) @ lookback_seo.js?hash=a658c0f8fd82680b329114c5e62d2bb35a458f36:478
```

the code responsible is:

```js
  Meta.config({                                                                                      // 165
    options: {                                                                                       // 166
      title: defaultTitle                                                                            // 167
    }                                                                                                // 168
  });
```

Comment: Are you certain it's because of 1.5.2 update? I'm having the same issue pop up in one of my meteor projects which is not 1.5.2. But the error seemed harmless and the functionality still works.

Comment: its broken for me, had to use another package. maybe it is the update, i couldnt bother to look into it. ive lost enough hair over it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no support for this, even the github issues section was disabled.

Switched to https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/ms-seo, good documentation and worked perfectly the first time even though its  more outdated.

Answer (score 0):

This package depends on [yasinuslu:blaze-meta](https://atmospherejs.com/yasinuslu/blaze-meta) that is no longer updated...